# Calling a Composable function from an android module in the same project

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-gradle-plugin, android-jetpack-compose

I have an android module (ComposeLib) as part of the same project as the app. It's just to test out using Compose from a library. In the Project Structure dialog I added ComposeLib as an implementation dependency of app.

[image: Android Studio Project View]

`build.gradle` (:app) contains...

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0-rc01'
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-appcompat-theme:0.16.0"

    implementation project(path: ':ComposeLib')
    ...
}
```

`Atoms.kt` in ComposeLib consists of...

```
class Atoms {
    @Composable
    fun CounterButton(count: Int, updateCount: (Int) -> Unit) {
        Button( onClick = {updateCount(count+1)},
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(MaterialTheme.colors.secondary)){
            Text("Clicked $count times")
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `MainActivity.kt` I am trying to use `CounterButton`...

```
import com.example.composelib.Atoms

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val myComposeView = findViewById<ComposeView>(R.id.composeView)
        myComposeView.setContent {
            val counter = remember{ mutableStateOf(0) }

            AppCompatTheme {
                CounterButton( // <== Unresolved Reference!?
                    count = counter.value,
                    updateCount = {newCount -> counter.value = newCount})
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see in the lower left of the screenshot the app cant find `CounterButton` from ComposeLib.Atoms. Any idea why?

This code works if I put `CounterButton()` in the app in `MainActivity`, so it's not a Jetpack problem it's a build configuration problem.

I also tried qualifying the call to `CounterButton` every way I could think of (`Atoms.CounterButton`, `public.example.composelib.Atoms.CounterButton`, etc). Even code completion doesn't recognize it.

How do I reference a `@Composable` function from another module in the same project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined your Composable inside `class Atoms` for some reason, so this function should be called on a class instance.

It's totally fine to define composable functions without any classes, just like

```
@Composable
fun CounterButton(count: Int, updateCount: (Int) -> Unit) {
}
```

It's already in some package so I don't think any container is much needed. But in case you wanna add some kind of modularity, you can replace `class` with `object`, in this case you'll be able to call it as `Atoms.CounterButton`

Comment: Bingo! Java habits die hard. Thanks